# Simplifying an indefinite integral representing the calculation of an average

Tags: indefinite-integrals, average

I have an equation for a term $z_i$:

$$
z_i = \ln\frac{a_iR+p_i}{T_o* tan\theta_i }
$$

This represents a value in a grid, at location $i$, with the grid representing a geographic area.  To get the average value of $z_i$ over the geographic area, I believe this is the proper representation:

$$
z_{avg} = \frac{1}{A}\int_A[\ln(\frac{a_iR+p_i}{T_o* tan\theta_i})]dA
$$

In hoping to separate out parts of this equation for substitution into other equations, I develop this:

$$
z_{avg} = \frac{1}{A}\int_A[\ln(\frac{a_i}{T_o* tan\theta_i}) + \ln(R+\frac{p_i}{a_i})]dA
$$

Is there anyway to pull the second ln() term out of the integral?  Similarly, since this grid is made up of defined area cells, how quickly can I make the transition from using the indefinite integral to a mere summation from i to N for all grid cells?  (with N being the total number of grid cells)

Comment: Should you divide the integral by the area?

Comment: @Marty Yes totally forgot that!

Comment: New to mathTex and just getting everything else right (or near-right) took a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment.

$\ln(\frac{a_iR+p_i}{T_o* tan\theta_i})
=\ln(a_iR+p_i)-\ln(T_o* tan\theta_i)
$
so this would split the integral
into two parts.

Comment: yes, but for reasons I didn't want to go into here, I need to keep the left hand term as close to $\ln(\frac{a_i}{T_o* tan\theta_i})$ as possible.  I have another equation like  $ln R = ...$ that I am hoping to substitute in at some point...And is there any chance this is my uncle Martin Cohen?  Ahaha, should've looked at your bio - it is not, sadly?